# WPF метод блокирует интерфейс

Tags: wpf, многопоточность

Добрый день.

Подскажите, как можно выполнить длительную функцию, чтобы не тормозилась отрисовка интерфейса на WPF.

Что делаю:

1. Есть главная форма, в которой вызывается длительный метод.
2. Перед вызовом этого метода показывается окно, в котором через DispatcherTimer выполняется анимация (картинка крутится).
3. После выполнения метода окно скрывается.

Метод должен отработать полностью и вернуть результат своей работы. Пока метод не выполнится, основной алгоритм программы выполняться не должен.

Как мне можно такое сделать?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Есть тысячи разных способов, но рекомендуемый на текущий момент — async/await.

Попробуйте например так:

```
async void ShowComputation()
{
    var w = new ComputationWindow();
    w.Show();
    await Task.Run(model.PerformYourComputationHere);
    w.Hide();
}
```